# Flutter - Clipping Text ignoring word breaks

Tags: flutter

In flutter when you use either `TextOverflow.clip` or `TextOverflow.ellipses` it clips the text at the word border when there are multiple words in the text.

However when the text data of `Text()` is only a single long word, it simply clips it at the last possible place.

Example: on a Captioned Image I don't want the label "Mr Ihaveanunusuallylongsurname" to show only "Mr" below the image, when all except the last few characters could fit.

[image]

Here on the middle photo you can see a lot of space is available after the "Mr...: .... I want at as much as possible of `Mr Ihaveanunusuallylongsurname` to be displayed in the available space to help the user to identify which is which.

How can Text() be made to clip ignoring word breaks, like when there is only a single word in the text?

```dart
class ClippedText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final TextStyle style;
  final int maxLines;

  const ClippedText(this.text,
      {Key key, this.textAlign, this.style, this.maxLines})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: style,
      textAlign: textAlign,
      maxLines: maxLines ?? 10,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );
  }
}
```

Note:  I use the above ClippedText in stead of Text().  Normally text wraps when maxLines is not set.  However to achieve this effect while using ClippedText I need to provide the encapsulated Text widget with a default value for maxLines that is not null.  I have not been able to figure out what the real default is that is passed to Text when maxLines is not provided.

Comment: Did you try using the `FittedBox` this will ensure the text will fit in the Container.
It will however make the font size smaller.

Comment: I have not tried FittedBox, and that sounds usefull in some cases!  In this case however I want to NOT make the text smaller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
        body: Container(
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red[200],
          child: Text(
            'Mr Ihaveanunusuallylongsurname'.replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Life saver! \u00A0